# How to trigger a catchError and retryWhen/retry - RXJS

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, rxjs, redux-observable

I am using redux-observables together with rxjs and [backoff rxjs](https://blog.angularindepth.com/power-of-rxjs-when-using-exponential-backoff-a4b8bde276b0) for retry, now I have this epic where it will request on server, if the request fails it will dispatch a redux action and will retry the function.

```
defer(callApi).pipe(
  catchError((error) => {
    return actions.hasError(error) // dispatch to redux
  }),

  // this should retry the request 10 times
  retryBackoff({
    shouldRetry: true,
    initialInterval: 1000,
    maxRetries: 10
  })
```

Doing the code above seems to only do 1 thing (whichever goes first). How can I make it so I can trigger an action when there's an error and retry at the same time?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `tap` to execute side effects on errors without catching the error if `retryBackoff` is used to recover from errors.

```
defer(callApi).pipe(
  tap({ error: e => actions.hasError(e) }),

  // this should retry the request 10 times
  retryBackoff({
    shouldRetry: true,
    initialInterval: 1000,
    maxRetries: 10
  })
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply rethrow from you `catchError` block So that it will still get picked up by the `retryBackoff`

```
defer(callApi).pipe(
  catchError((error) => {
    return concat(actions.hasError(error), throwError(error))
  }),

  // this should retry the request 10 times
  retryBackoff({
    shouldRetry: true,
    initialInterval: 1000,
    maxRetries: 10
  })
)
```